# Appending an integer and a list to a list of lists as a single list

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append an integer and a list of numbers to a list a.

```
a = 4
b = [3,1]
c = []
c.append([a,b])
```

The list c is [[4,[3,1]]] but instead, I wanted to append a single list so c should be [[4,3,1]]. It is difficult to use the extend function in this case because the length of c and the index to which the integer and list need to be appended are variable. Also, this operation of appending a list and integer needs to be carried out with several lists of different lengths. Can someone explain how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one simple way to do it, as long as the number of lists and integers you are planning to append is not large,

```
a = 4
b = [3,1]
b2 = [5,6,7]
b3 = [2]

b.insert(0,a)
c = []

c.append([x for x in b])
c[0] += b2
c[0] += b3

print(c)
```

Here I extended your example to cover two additional list. The code should print:

```
[[4, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2]]
```

Basically, you prepend the integer to the first list, `b`. Then you use a list comprehension to create a sublist out of the new `b` in `c`. Finally, you simply concatenate all the other lists to it with `+=`. `c[0]` is the location of the inner - target list.

This method is not very efficient, and is pretty "manual", but again, it seems suitable for small number of lists with not too many elements.

Answer (score 0):

a = 4

b = [3,1]

c = []

for i in b:

c.append(i)

c.append(a)

print(c)

[3, 1, 4]

this is work it.